# Programmatically, how to make an app return to previous view when it got to the screen in the first place using a push segue

Tags: xcode, view, back, segue

I am creating an app where if it cannot load a webpage, it displays an error and returns to the previous screen. I am having difficulty getting it to return to the previous screen.

I am using a push segue to have it go to the screen in the first place.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

A push segue requires a navigation controller, and with a navigation controller you can use popViewControllerAnimated:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Though many would advocate using delegation for something like this (perhaps even with modal instead of navigation controller).

Comment: I get an EXC_Bad_access, and "nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar" I am sure your code is right but I am forgetting something. Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your post to add some of the specific code you are using? Specifically the portion of how you get the web view on screen, and the part where you are trying to pop it off (perhaps including the displaying of the message).

Comment: In this app I have practically no code. Everything is from StoryBoard. The push is built into buttons. There is no "real" webview there. It is a 3x3 pixel area because I could not get reachability to work. If that "webview" cannot load, it displays an error message even though it doesn't make a difference. There is no navigationController code built into the .m or .h itself. Here is the entire .m, http://pastie.org/4111440      You may have to put phrases in simple terms as I am only 13 and this is one of my first real applications. Thank you for your patience with me.